# AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11 doesn't work: syntax error near unexpected token `,'

Tags: c++11, configure, autotools, autoconf

Trying to use AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11 in my configure.ac file like this:

```
...
AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11(, optional)
...
```

However, results in error:

```
./configure: line 16126: syntax error near unexpected token `,'
./configure: line 16126: `AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11(, optional)'
```

I've also placed [this file](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf-archive.git;a=blob_plain;f=m4/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4) into m4 directory next to configure.ac file and have `AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])` called in configure.ac in the very beginning.
Did anyone faced anything like that before?

Comment: That same file works for me using the same configuration as you. Perhaps check the previous lines in your configure.ac for something there?

Comment: Which versions of autoconf automake do you have? Mines are 2.69 and 1.11 respectively.

Comment: autoconf: 2.69 and automake: 1.13.4 and g++: 4.8.3

Answer (score 2):

My problem solved with running `autoreconf -f` instread of `autoconf`.

https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/autoreconf-Invocation.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding `ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = ${ACLOCAL_FLAGS} -I m4` to the top-level Makefile.am helped to resolve this issue for me.